# Finding CDF of $Y$ when $Y=1/X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

$X$ be a uniform random variable on $[1,3]$. $Y=1/X$. What is the CDF of $Y$?

My attempt so far:
CDF of $Y$ by definition:

$= P(Y\le y)\\
= P (1/X \le y)\\
= P (X\ge 1/y)$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Observe that $P(X>1/y)=1-P(X\le y)=1-CDF_X(1/y)$

Answer (score 1):

> My attempt so far: CDF of Y by definition: $= P(Y\leq y) \\ = P (1/X \leq y) \\ = P (X\geq  1/y)$

Correct. You also know $X\sim\mathcal{U}[1,3]$ and so $P(X\leq x)= \tfrac{x-1}2\cdot\mathbf 1_{1\leqslant x\lt 3}+\mathbf 1_{3\leqslant x}$